# Non-Printable Character when creating directory with WSL

Tags: bash, directory, non-printing-characters

First time WSL user. When I run this bash script in WSL that creates a directory there is a non-printable character tacked on to the end.

[image]

It doesn't matter if I'm in /mnt/e /mnt/c or mnt/e/some_folder/ same result

My test.sh script-

```
mkdir myfolder
cd myfolder
export TOP_FOLDER=`pwd`
cd $TOP_FOLDER
```

The resulting command line-

```
rayh@computer42:/mnt/e$ bash test.sh
test.sh: line 4: cd: $'/mnt/e/myfolder\r\r\r': No such file or directory
rayh@computer42:/mnt/e$
```

Any idea what's going on?

Ray

Comment: Those are carriage return characters. They're in the script file. Remove them.

Comment: I appears I had the EOL set wrong in notepad++. Changed it to UNIX and now it works. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Not very versed in Linux and especially in a mixed environment like WSL. Turns out that I need to have my notepad++ EOL set to UNIX when editing scripts to be run in WSL. Didn't know that. Thanks to user Barmar for pointing me in the right direction.